# Can't seem to get Jekyll to see posts that are in subdirectories from the root folder

Tags: yaml, markdown, jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I have used collections in my Jekyll website for GitHub Pages. I'm trying to get Jekyll to see the Markdown files inside the collection folder, `_projects`.

Here's a rundown of the file structure:

```
root
 │
 ├─ _projects
 │       │
 │       ├─ project_1.md
 │       └─ project_2.md
 │
 └─ /*Rest of the Jekyll folders and files, _posts, _includes, etc.*/
```

At the moment, I realized that you must put the Markdown files in the root, so Jekyll can be able to see and parse the files to display them when after you clicked a link that points to them via permalinks. But it cannot "see" the Markdown files if the files are not in the root folder, after testing quite a while.

Is there a way to let Jekyll see and parse files inside the subfolder, `_projects`, just like how it can see files in the root folder? Maybe I need to set something up in the `_config.yml`, I guess?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To someone who downvoted, please tell me what's wrong with this post, or please provide feedback as to what you feel negative about. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OP tom-mai78101](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1016891/tom-mai78101) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686088/cant-seem-to-get-jekyll-to-see-posts-that-are-in-subdirectories-from-the-root-f/26687170?noredirect=1#comment41972033_26687170) the the article "[Jekyll Blog From a Subdirectory](http://h3manth.com/new/blog/2013/jekyll-blog-from-a-subdirectory/)" from [Hemanth.HM](http://h3manth.com/new/)

> has confirmed my guesses that **subdirectories are only defined by the permalinks in the Markdown files**, and not through the folders within the repository.
>   [I quickly wrote a code snippet, and created a few Markdown files shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2yDu.png), I am now able to create webpages using Markdown files nested within the `_posts` folder.
>   **In short, there's no need to use collections in the `_config.yml`, and just use the default `_posts`**.
>   It would've been better if there is a way to change the default permalink setup in the `_config.yml`.

---

The question "[Jekyll not generating pages in subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18401297/6309)" could be relevant, in order to make some pages being generated in a subfolder.

Or you could [use a different baseurl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16638250/6309). (Jekyll 1.0+)

Or use the `_include` folder (see "[Jekyll paginate `blog` as subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20523663/6309)")

---

Or, The article "[Running Your Jekyll Blog from a Subdirectory](http://joshbranchaud.com/blog/2013/03/02/Running-Your-Jekyll-Blog-from-a-Subdirectory.html)" (from [**Josh Branchaud**](http://joshbranchaud.com/)) seems to address your situation:

#### Solution 1

> Create a directory called `blog` in your public html directory (that is, in the directory that your domain points to). 
>   Assuming you are using some sort of deployment scheme ([GitHub pages](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/) or [deployment methods](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/deployment-methods/)), you need to have that deployment scheme tell Jekyll to deploy to the `blog` directory instead of the directory it is currently using.

(in your case `blog` would be `projects`)

#### Solution 2

> Start by creating a directory locally where you have your Jekyll `blog` setup.
>   This directory will sit along side `_posts`, `_site`, `css`, etc.
>   **This is only going to hold non-post files such as `index.html`.
>
>   The `blog` posts will still go in the _posts directory**.
>
> **Next, we are going to tell Jekyll that we want it to take our blog posts and put them inside a directory called blog when it generates them.
>
>   This can be done by adding a permalink setting to the `_config.yml` file**.
>   Add a line like this to the top of the file:

```
permalink: /blog/:categories/:year/:month/:day/:title.html.
```

> The default (which you have probably been using) puts `posts` in a directory structure starting with the category, followed by the date, and finally with the title of the blog post as the name of the html file.
>   Which, spelled out would be

```
/:categories/:year/:month/:day/:title.html.
```

> Does that look familiar? Sure does. It is what we have used above, sans the `/blog` part.
>   We are essentially emulating the default directory structure and while adding our `blog` directory at the beginning.
>
> Lastly, you are going to want to add an `index.html` file to the `blog` directory that you created.
>   This way, when a person goes to `mydomain.com/blog/` they can see what `blog` posts you have to offer.
>   This index page is going to more or less mirror exactly what you had setup originally for listing your `blog` posts.

Comment: Same kind of solution (using permalink) http://h3manth.com/new/blog/2013/jekyll-blog-from-a-subdirectory/

Comment: I was doing a bit of experimenting with the `_posts` for 6 hours, searching in Stack Overflow. I noticed that Markdown files will only be seen if the files are named accordingly with the structure: `YYYY-MM-DD-TITLE.md`. Adding these files into subdirectories of `_posts` would still allow the files to be seen by Jekyll, except for the fact that you must add your own permalink to each Markdown files. The user-defined permalinks in the Markdown files allow cleaner-looking URLs upon generating the webpages for each of them. Just as I was about to answer my own question, your answer pops up.

Comment: I read through your commented link, and have confirmed my guesses that subdirectories are only defined by the permalinks in the Markdown files, and not through the folders within the repository. [I quickly wrote a code snippet, and created a few Markdown files shown here](http://i.imgur.com/lGSX42r.png), I am now able to create webpages using Markdown files nested within the `_posts` folder. In short, there's no need to use collections in the `_config.yml`, and just use the default `_posts`. It would've been better if there is a way to change the default permalink setup in the `_config.yml`.

Comment: @tom_mai78101 I agree. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Thank you. If someone knows how to use collections and custom file name structures, like `TITLE-YEAR.md` or `YEAR-TITLE-DAY.md`, while still allowing Jekyll to see the Markdown files, whether they would be in `_posts` or in user-defined collections folder, it would be very helpful and could be added to the official Jekyll documentation.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** : My first answer was completely wrong. I was talking

### _config.yml

```
collections:
  project:
    output: true
```

### _project/project_1.md

```
---
layout: project
title: project
---

## Yo!

Project in **strong** yo `inline code`

    some code
    yolo !
```

### _layouts/project.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  {% include head.html %}
  <body>
    {% include header.html %}
    <div class="page-content">
      <div class="wrapper">
        {{ content }}
      </div>
    </div>
    {% include footer.html %}
  </body>
</html>
```

You now have a `project/project_1.html` page.

No need to use `include:` parameter in order to Jekyll to see collection folder or subfolder.

`exclude:` parameter can be used to ignore a subfolder in the collection.

**End Edit**

---

**Old answer** (nothing to do with collection)

Your `_project` folder is ignored by Jekyll, just like any [underscored folder](https://help.github.com/articles/files-that-start-with-an-underscore-are-missing/)

To force Jekyll to parse files in this folder, in your `_config.yml` you can add :

```
include:
  - _project
```

`jekyll build` and all is good !

Comment: I thought underscored folders are for collections in the `_config.yml` file. If not, what is the official way of using collections in a folder, and how to put the files in, so that it corresponds to the `{% for element in site.collection_name %}`in Liquid for Jekyll?

Comment: You are right, I'm completely wrong in my first answer. I was talking about pages not collections. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I saw the edited section. It's now working! Felt good to actually understand another confusing part of Jekyll. I still feel the documentation needs to explain how to use collections with nested folders, so that Liquid parses them and knows what to generate. I could have a collection of posts within nested folders, like `_project > someFolder > anotherFolder > project_1.md`, and wouldn't know how to let Jekyll see `project_1.md` without help if the documentation didn't explain edge cases like this.

Comment: Can't edit previous comments. I meant to say, in the `_config.yml`, when setting up collections. If the collections can see all nested folders when specifying the root folder of a collection, wouldn't that be equal to saying that you are `including` the folders? Or do you need to `include` the root folder, so that the collections can see the nested folders and posts in those subdirectories?

Comment: No need to use `include`. You talk about posts but they are collections not posts, it's not the same type of object.

Comment: So, if I set collections in the `_config.yml`, the Markdown files (which I'm referring to as 'posts' for all references above) nested in the collection folders are seen by Jekyll, however deeply-nested they are, correct? I'm just trying to nail down the last tiny bit of confusion.

Comment: Yes, everything contained in you collection folder and subfolders is seen.