# How can I install a Jekyll blog in a subdirectory of my Github user page?

Tags: git, github, jekyll, github-pages

As far as I know, one can host a Jekyll blog either directly on one's User page or in a subdirectory of one's User page. I want the latter, that is, I want to access my blog via **MYUSERNAME.github.io/blog**.

Scouring the web, I found a couple of guides, but I still haven't managed to make it work. Basically what I did was:

1) created my User repo: MYUSERNAME.github.io -> works perfectly, of course
2) created a blog repo called "blog" at MYUSERNAME/blog. I initialised it with a simple README file ("Blog: personal blog for my website").

This is what I did afterwards:

```
git clone https://github.com/MYUSERNAME/blog.git
cd blog 
jekyll new blog
```

Jekyll blog gets correctly installed in my local folder

```
cd blog 
git checkout -b gh-pages
git branch
```

This command shows I now have two branches, master and gh-pages, with gh-pages active

```
jekyll build 
jekyll serve
```

The jekyll blog shows correctly. Now I commit all of it to remote:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

this results into

```
`[gh-pages 8b4c48f] initial commit
7 files changed, 168 insertions(+)
create mode 100644 blog/.gitignore
create mode 100644 blog/Gemfile
create mode 100644 blog/Gemfile.lock
create mode 100644 blog/_config.yml
create mode 100644 blog/_posts/2017-05-27-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown
create mode 100644 blog/about.md
create mode 100644 blog/index.md`
```

then:

```
git push origin gh-pages
```

which results into

```
Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Writing objects: 100% (11/11), 3.48 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 11 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/MYUSERNAME/blog.git
   de26b53..8b4c48f  gh-pages -> gh-pages
```

Everything looks successful right? When I go to Github I see that the jekyll blog has been successfully uploaded to the blog repo under the gh-branch.

**However, when I go check MYUSERNAME.github.io/blog all I see is just the README files's contents, that is "Blog: personal blog for my website". I can't see my blog.**

What's going on? How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't seem to get Jekyll to see posts that are in subdirectories from the root folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686088/cant-seem-to-get-jekyll-to-see-posts-that-are-in-subdirectories-from-the-root-f)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your blog files inside another directory.

```
-blog  <-------your blog file must be here
--blog
----your blog files
```

When you use

```
git clone https://github.com/MYUSERNAME/blog.git
```

it will create directory with name `blog` 
and when you use

```
jekyll new blog
```

it also will create directory with name blog inside first blog directory. So you will have `/blog/blog/` and that will not working and you need to use

```
jekyll new .
```

insted of `jekyll new blog` so Jekyll will not create new directory but install within a current directory and that will solve your problem

Comment: I think the OP wants to create a subdirectory, that is the problem